# Timeout when calling Soap WebService through PHP Curl

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

This one's making me insane. I'm getting timeouts when executing a SOAP curl call, despite doing everything exactly as documentation directly from the webservice says.

How can I better debug stuff like this, and better understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after many attempts the issue laid on the web service itself, their testing tables were outdated and were causing issues when sending requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging using [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or Postman and made sure you get the expected results before writing php code?